# How do you change the listening port for a Confluence installation?

Tags: tomcat, port, confluence

I have a Windows 2008 server running:

- MS Team Foundation server on port 80
- Atlassians Jira running on port 81
- JetBrains Team City running on port 82
- Default web on IIS is running on 8090 or similar

All applications are working.

However, I have installed Confluence wiki from Atlassian today, and I am unable to change the port from 8080 to 83. I have tried to follow the information here, but I am unable to find the server.xml file. 
[Change listen post for Confluence](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Change+listen+port+for+Confluence+Standalone).

At this time I believe that either:

1. The evaluation version I have installed cannot be configured
   or
2. I am looking in the wrong folder

I do not have that much experience with Tomcat, but since I have been able to change ports for both Jira and Team City (that run in one Tomcat instance each), I should be able to find this file :-)

I have checked the installation directory and the one under 'users\\app data...' without any luck. I also did a full search on the server without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned the following from Atlassian support:

> I would highly recommend you to install the Standalone Edition of Confluence in order to have more control of the instance. The evaluation installer, as the name suggests, is generally used for evaluation purpose only.
>   Then you can refer to this document to change your Confluence Port.

Most likely everything is hard coded in the eval installation to make it easy for the potential customers.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew is right the instructions are correct the server.xml `<Connector port=xxx>` is what you need to change.

If you need to know if you're looking in the right place just check where the exe is as referenced in the Windows service then simply ../conf/server.xml.

Comment: ah i misread that this was an eval edition

Answer (score 0):

How about simply doing a find across the whole drive for "server.xml"?

The instructions pretty much cover it.

Comment: I did that already. Thought I wrote that in the initial post. No luck finding it there.

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. I'm surprised it's not clearer than it seems to be for you, there's nothing unusual about the Confluence installation from a Tomcat perspective.

Comment: Well - the problem was most likely because of a hardcoded setting in the eval version. So I wasn't that stupid :)